# Clearing a product from nopCommerce cache programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, nopcommerce

I have run into a problem where I need to manually click the clear cache button for a specific product to appear correct on a specific page after it's saved.

I'm wondering how I can go about this with code, but only clear the cache for that product.

clearing complete cache can be done like this:

```
var _cacheManager = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ICacheManager>();
_cacheManager.Clear();
```

I have tried doing it like this but it didn't work.

```
var product = _productService.GetProductById(productModel.Id);
var productTemplateCacheKey = string.Format(ModelCacheEventConsumer.PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_MODEL_KEY,
                productModel.Id);
_cacheManager.Remove(productTemplateCacheKey);
```

Not sure how to go about this, anyone got any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: 1) Which version of nop are you using? 2) I don't think you'd need to clear the cache after saving the product. 3) Are you referring nopCommerce default code? or you made changes?

Comment: @Div using nopcommerce v3.70. it's not default either and customized

Comment: There might be some another issue. You don't need to clear cache after updating a product every time!

Comment: @div we are using the method to index static html files on category pages `GenerateCategoryPageAsHtml(int categoryId)`

Comment: I don't have have code of 3.70; but I believe that is your custom method. And what do you mean by static html files? will it store whole category pages as html?

Comment: Ahh ok, yeah it builds a html file of the 40 products and served that up as a speed improvement. But doesn't store paginated pages or filtered pages

Comment: Okay, I don't think this would better solution for speed improvements, you could use no sql to store your data. However if you can publish your code on a public repo. I will take look at the issue you are facing.

Comment: Hi @Div sorry was out of office all weekend. I think if it's not possible to clear out the cache for only one product I'm going to have to rethink how I go about this.
Sorry but I can't share our repository as a huge amount of money and hours have gone into the code.
I'm not a fan of the static html pages but other developers built them.

Comment: Hey, that's all okay, I do understand your concern.